# How to make Intentservice repeating a job?

Tags: android

I have intentservice that notify when found value in myDataBsae but if data is null should not  notify me ,so

1. How can I make my Intentservice check content of myDataBase every 50 second (I used AlarmManager but my service notify me every 50 second in spite of my database = null ,  )?
2. I want my intentservice work separately thread , when I triggering  it

my service is :

```
    public class ShowTimeServer extends IntentService  {
NotificationManager nm;
static final int uniqueID=326534;
public ShowTimeServer() {
    super("ShowTimeServer");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ShowTimeDB RetrieverDB =new ShowTimeDB(this);
    RetrieverDB.open();
    String data = RetrieverDB.getShowNotify();
    RetrieverDB.close();



    if (!(data.equals(null))){

        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,TodayShow.class);
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0  );
        CharSequence x=(CharSequence) data;
        Notification n=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"YOU HAVE SHOW" ,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, "ShowTime", x, pi);
        n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        nm.notify(uniqueID,n);
        //pi.cancel();
        //nm.cancel(uniqueID);

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. intentService isn't supposed to do things every X seconds. for this there are plenty of other solutions. if you insist of using a service for this task, you can make it a normal foreground/background service (depending if you wish to do it when the user has left the app) and then do it there.
2. intentService already runs on a different thread. that's why you can do a long operation on the onHandleIntent method.

Comment: did you mean that I can't make runnable or timer in it

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to. please explain more.

Comment: I mean can I use sach this code below and put my notification code in it
***>
private TimerTask mTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Whatever you want
          postDelayed(this, REPEAT_INTERVAL);   // rinse and repeat...
        }
    };